# Grammar question about modifiers

Tags: grammar, modifiers

I'm not sure if this statement is grammatically correct. It sounds fine, but I'm not sure if the 'with the...' part is right.

> With the end of the Great War came a great revolution in the entertainment industry.

Comment: Sounds perfectly grammatical to me. Try substituting 'Accompanying the end of the Great War...'

Comment: Or "Following the Great War came a great ..."

Comment: @WS2: Just as a test, you mean—not as a preferred substitute, right?

Comment: It's a perfectly normal rhetoric use of _with_, like other participles, adverbs, prepositions, and subordinate conjunctions. Nothing unusual here at all. What makes you think it's not kosher?

Comment: Perhaps it's because there's subject-dependent inversion, and so, maybe you'll feel better about the sentence if you saw the non-inverted version: *"A great revolution in the entertainment industry came with the end of the Great War."*

Comment: @Cerberus  Yes, just as a way of understanding the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

'With the end of the Great War' is a prepositional phrase which acts as adverb in the sentence. The adverbial prepositional phrase modifies the verb 'came'. In cases where the prepositional phrases are positioned at the beginning of the sentence, it is also possible reverse the positioning of the phrases in order to test whether or not the whole sentence is gramatically sound. See FE's comment above.